# I need to convert below python code into nodejs but I couldn't find any equivalent code for "sasl_oauth_token_provider" this property

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, oauth-2.0, librdkafka

I've this code working in python, I need to convert this into nodejs but I couldn't find any equivalent code for `sasl_oauth_token_provider` this property.

```
import time
from kafka import *
from kafka.errors import KafkaTimeoutError
from oauthlib.oauth2 import BackendApplicationClient
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth2Session

producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers='xxx',
                         security_protocol='SASL_SSL',
                         ssl_check_hostname=True,
                         sasl_mechanism='OAUTHBEARER',
                         sasl_plain_username=client_id,
                         sasl_plain_password=client_secret,
                         sasl_oauth_token_provider="xxx",
                         )
```

For nodejs I'm using node-rdkafka library and closest equivalent code I've got is -

```
const kafka = require('node-rdkafka');

const producer = new kafka.Producer({
'metadata.broker.list': 'xxx',
'security.protocol': 'sasl_ssl',
'sasl.mechanism': 'OAUTHBEARER',
'sasl.username': 'xxx',
'sasl.password': 'xxx',
});
```

Comment: Assuming you used confluent-kafka-python and are migrating to node-rdkafka, all of the properties are the exact same.... So, what libraries are you using?

Comment: for your clarification I've modified the question please check

Comment: I haven't used oauth, but you can find all rdkafka properties at https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/blob/master/CONFIGURATION.md

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I've found `node-rdkafka` has no way to `sasl_oauth_token_provider` use this configuration property, so I had to abandon it and use `KafkaJS` which supports this.